# iOS facebook comments add to comment box

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-comments

We have comment box on our website and want to implement it to our iOS app. We can fetch all comments from box and parse json but cannot add any. Using graph api for fetching. Is there way to add comments to comment box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there way to add comments to comment box?

No, there is not.

---

Facebook recently introduced a feature called “Comment Mirroring”, which makes it possible to have comments synchronized between your external URL, and a Facebook post containing that URL. What users comment on the one will automatically show up in the other as well, and vice versa.

And via API you can comment on posts on Facebook - so that could be a possible alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. Facebook had same answer from 2011, but no updates